# Submitting data from front end to back end in Go

Tags: http, go

I have simple website. Go with JavaScript. Now I get this message  "http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls" and I know that a have another header open. But I don't know where and I'm struggling to find a solution.

```
func (t *Server) RootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var c *entities.Korisnik
    var k *entities.Kilometri
    var a *entities.Auto

    if c = t.authentication(w, r); c == nil {
        return
    }

    gk, err := t.store.GetKilometri(c)

    if errorEval(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError) {
        return
    }
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if r.FormValue("debug") == "true" {
        s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(&Bla{c, gk}, "", "    ")
        w.Write(s)
        return
    } else {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        errorEval(w, json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Bla{c, gk}), http.StatusInternalServerError)

    }

    log.Println("0")
    if errorEval(w, json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&Input{a, k}), http.StatusBadRequest) {
        log.Println("1")
        return
    }
    err = t.store.NewKilometri(k, c, a)
    log.Println("2")
    if errorEval(w, err, http.StatusInternalServerError) {
        return

    }
}
```

I get this in my terminal

```
015/10/20 16:12:32 0
2015/10/20 16:12:32 EOF
2015/10/20 16:12:32 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
2015/10/20 16:12:32 1
2015/10/20 16:12:32 0
2015/10/20 16:12:32 EOF
2015/10/20 16:12:32 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
2015/10/20 16:12:32 1

func errorEval(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, status int) bool {
if err == nil {
    return false
}
log.Println(err)
http.Error(w, errorString[status], status)
return true
```

}

Comment: you need to show what  `errorEval` does

Comment: `errorEval(w, json.NewEncoder(w...` is not checked. Possible that is writing headers, and you are continuing to do other things.

Comment: As a side note, I would say that generally, the response writing should be in the handler function which in this case is your `RootHandler`. Having `errorEval` makes it difficult to trace and isn't quite beneficial. You moved the conditional one layer down to check the error but you're returning a boolean to yet again use in another conditional.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `errorEval` likely writes the status code and maybe a body if an error is encountered. Most places you call it you check the return and return from your handler if it handles an error.

In the case of `errorEval(w, json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Bla{c, gk}), http.StatusInternalServerError)` you are not checking the return.

My guess is, there is some json error and the handler is writing a 500 response, and you are continuing to do other things which in turn try to write additional responses.